# Proper way to check QObject derived class type in Qt

Tags: qt, types, qobject

Lets say I have a two classes:

```
class A : public QObject {};
class B : public QObject {};
```

then I go

```
QObject *a = new A();
QObject *b = new B();
```

now, how do I make sure that "a" is an instance of class A, and "b" is an instance of class B?

currently I do something like this:

```
if (a->inherits(A::staticMetaObject.className())) {
...
} else if (a->inherits(A::staticMetaObject.className())) {
...
```

is there a better way?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use `qobject_cast<MyClass*>(instance)` on QObject derived classes and check the return value. If `instance` cannot be cast to `MyClass*`, the return value will be NULL.

Comment: Well.. looking into inherits function source shows that internally it uses qobject_cast<T *> to verify object type